# why does the crosstab result depend on colnames and rownames?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Depending on whether I pass `rownames` and `colnames` to [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) the results vary. Why is that?

*example*:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1, 1, 2]})
other = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1, 2, 2]})
print(pd.crosstab(index=df["a"], columns=other["a"]))
print(pd.crosstab(index=df["a"], columns=other["a"], rownames=["df"], colnames=["other"]))
```

*output*:

```
a  1  2
a      
1  1  0
2  0  2

other  1  2
df         
1      1  1
2      0  1
```

EDIT:

- python: 3.6.9
- pandas: 1.1.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this on version 1.2?

Comment: For me working well, it seems some oldier pandas bug.

Comment: Uff. I can't update pandas from `1.1.0` to `1.2` because it requires `python 3.7`

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22529